# Port Forwarding in apache

Tags: apache, portforwarding

My web server is resolved from other users outside my internal network. The issue is that it redirects me to the router page on my PC. Anyway to fix this, I have to use a proxy to see my own web server, and it can be dangerous to my privacy and code.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a fix because that is done for security by your router and since the request is coming back to your router from your ip it will think you are trying to go to your router page so to be able to see the site just follow the following steps:

Go to "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc" and MOVE the "HOSTS" file to your desktop.
Open it up and follow the steps below but in this example STACKOVERFLOW.COM will be the URL and the local server ip is 192.168.1.255:

---

**# Copyright (c) 1993-1999 Microsoft Corp.** 

        **# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.**

        **# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each**

        **# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should**

        **# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.**

        **# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one**

       **# space.**

        **# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual**

        **# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.**

**192.168.1.255 stackoverflow.com

        192.168.1.255 siteb.com

        192.168.1.255 sitec.net**

---

Copy all the code above the UNDERSCORE but DONT COPY THE UNDERSCORE.Paste it into your hosts file and change it aroud to suite your needs. Change the ip to your servers local ip and your url to the url u use to connect to the site with. Just make sure you SAVE THE FILE AND MOVE IT BACK TO YOUR ETC FOLDER!